# Convert DateTime with 12 hour AM/PM (no zero padding) to 24 hour format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I want to be able to sort my dataframe by ascending order of datetime but the format I have doesn't allow it to currently.

I have tried

```
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Times'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

df2['Times'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Times'], format='%H:%M:%S %p')
```

I currently have this

```
df2.iloc[:,0:2]


         Date     Times
0    1/2/2018   3:00 AM
1   10/3/2018   3:50 PM
2  10/10/2019  11:14 PM
```

and this is my desired output

```
         Date  Times
0  01/02/2018  03:00
1  10/03/2018  15:50
2  10/10/2019  23:14
```

or any output that will make it possible for me to sort by datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, main problem was use `%I` for match hour in 12h format and last use `%H` for hour in 24h format, check [`http://strftime.org/`](http://strftime.org/). Last add [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for custom output format:

```
print (df2)
         Date     Times
0    1/2/2018   3:00 AM
1   10/3/2018   3:50 PM
2  10/10/2019  11:14 PM

df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y').dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
df2['Times'] = (pd.to_datetime(df2['Times'].str.strip(), format='%I:%M %p')
                  .dt.strftime('%H:%M'))

print (df2)
         Date  Times
0  01/02/2018  03:00
1  10/03/2018  15:50
2  10/10/2019  23:14
```

Comment: how did you add that table btw? I  have to spam white spaces to get it to even remotely look like a table

Comment: I got this error when I run it: 'time data ' 3:00 PM ' does not match format '%I:%M%p' (match)'

Comment: @LseLibrary - there should be some data with another formats, if need replace another formats to `NaN`s add `errors='coerce'` parameter, answer was edited.

Comment: Not sure why but now I am getting all NaTs for the Times column

Comment: @LseLibrary - What is `print (df2['Times'].iloc[:10].tolist())` ?

Comment: it is [' 3:00 PM ', ' 3:50 PM ', ' 1:14 PM ', ' 1:16 PM ', ' 12:48 PM ', ' 1:24 PM ', ' 2:48 PM ', ' 12:57 PM ', ' 12:57 PM ', ' 1:02 PM ']

Comment: @LseLibrary - I found problem. There are traling whitespaces, so need `df2['Times'] = (pd.to_datetime(df2['Times'].str.strip(), format='%I:%M %p')
                      .dt.strftime('%H:%M'))`

Comment: Omg how did you even spot that? Is there a certain error to look out for?

Comment: @LseLibrary - yes if check list carefully, `' 3:00 PM '` - there are spaces :)